# How to protect files from power failure (Win7)

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, filesystems, disk

My VB.NET application uses config.xml file to store all configurations. This file is written often (every 20 seconds or so) as it also stores state of user's session etc. From time to time, users report this file to be suddenly of zero length or full of unknown characters and application is thus not executable.

I tracked the problem to find out that this happens when file is written short before power failure or even normal shutdown (!). I tested it with notepad  - I edited the file and unplugged power cord immediately after editing, then after reboot, file was corrupted. File is usually empty after initiating system shutdown, or it is full of zeros (bitwise) after power outage. So this doesn't look like issue of my application, but rather general OS or disk/FS issue.

This is happening on more than ten different PCs. All have Win7, NTFS, some have SSD disk, some not.

Can this be prevented? Can I ensure that file contains either data before the edit or data after the edit, but never ends up in corrupted state?

Comment: Don't overwrite an existing file.  Create a new file and use File.Replace().

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent, that the user will unplug power cord and system will unexpectively shutdown.

I believe, that you can work around it by storing multiple (at least two) files and if the last one is corrupted, use the previous one.

EDIT: This means, that should not save the same file when timer ticks. Because you didn't provided details, I can't suggest exact code change. You can define a boolean variable which you can negate when timer ticks and then switch saved file:

```
blnUseSecondaryFile = Not blnUseSecondaryFile
If blnSecondaryFile Then
   savepath = "file2.xml"
Else
   savepath = "file1.xml"
End If
```

Comment: this is basically what I am doing now, but I consider it a workaround rather than clean solution.

Comment: I know I can't prevent power failure, but I wonder if I can prevent the file being corrupted. What about windows system files for example? I believe windows has to protect them from this kind of error somehow, or your system would be damaged every now and then.

Comment: If there is no other way to protect files, this isn't a bad solution. Still I am afraid that if two writes happens short time after each other, both files might get corrupted.

Comment: Windows is using shadow copies to keep backup of system files. Also from Windows Vista, there's WinSxS folder which contains all version of binaries. These are only hardlinked to system32 folder. Microsoft Office is saving copies of your documents each X secs and if unexpectedly quits, it allows you to recover it and choose version. As far, as I know, there's no better solution for this situation. Maybe other filesystems (ext3, Reiser) handle this better, but I don't know.